# Google sheets: Форматирование таблицы Query запроса

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть таблица, из которой запросом query я получаю таблицу из id и названий предметов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в результате эта таблица отображалась в одной ячейке следующим образом:
item 1000, item1 1001, item2 1002

Есть функция JOIN, но она объединяет только массивы, а не таблицы, может это работает через arrayformula, но как, не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ с англ стековерфлоу:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443791/google-sheets-formatting-query-request

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B & " " & A2:A),B2:B<>""))
```